Proving Triangle Inequality from $\sqrt{1+|x+y|^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}{2}$
Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ From a calculus of variations problem, I was able to deduce that $\sqrt{1+|x+y|^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}{2}$ ($\star$). From this identity, I am asked to prove the triangle inequality $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$.
I played around with the identity ($\star$) algebraically, squaring both sides and using an approach similar to this reponse, which has an error in it. I have also thought about the problem in terms of convexity and a Jensen inequality, though I am not able to recover the triangle inequality. I have noted that $(\star)$ can be suggestively re-written as $$|(2, 2x+2y)| = |(1, 2x) + (1, 2y)| \leq |(1, 2x)| + |(1, 2y)|.$$ On the other hand, Iam wondering whether ($\star$) is even 'tight' enough to even deduce the triangle inequality, because whilst \begin{align} |x+y| \leq \sqrt{1+|x+y|^2} \text{ and }  |x|+|y| \leq \frac{\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}{2} \quad  \forall x, y, \end{align} it is not true that $\sqrt{1+|x+y|^2} \leq |x|+|y|$ (or even $|x|+|y| \leq \sqrt{1+|x+y|^2})$ $\forall x, y$. Thus, I am not sure how or whether it is possible to prove the triangle inequality from ($\star$).

are you sure this is true ? Triangle inequality becomes equality when the two vectors are "positively" parallel but does your inequality does not.

Applying the inequality to $(tx,ty)$ gives
$$
\sqrt{ 1 + t^2|x+y|^2 } \le \frac12 \left( \sqrt{ 1 + t^2 |2x|^2} + \sqrt{ 1 + t^2 |2y|^2} \right).
$$
Now divide by $t$, and let $t\to\infty$.
