Proving the triangle inequality from a given fact
We're given fact (1):
$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \sqrt{1+|x+y|^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{1+|2x|^2} + \sqrt{1+|2y|^2}}{2} $$
Using the Jensen's Inequality and fact (1), please prove the triangle inequality
$$|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$$
To start, I proved that the function $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2} $ is convex. It is clear how Jensen's inequality can be connected to fact (1), but I'm not sure how to connect the Inequality to the triangle inequality.
I would appreciate any hints/guidance for this problem.

Was this a recent contest or something? The same problem is posted in the following link 4 hours ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4956129/proving-triangle-inequality-from-sqrt1xy2-leq-frac-sqrt12x2

@Euclid It is not quite the same question.  Here, the OP insists on using only Jansen's inequality and the given inequality.  In the other, there is no restriction on using Jensen's only to accompany the given inequality.
